# Custom visitors and custom expanders in arangodb

Tags: javascript, arangodb, graph-traversal

Looking at the documentsaton it says that the traversal module (@arangodb/graph/traversal) is deprecated from version 3.4.0. Is there any other way to use custom visitors and expanders in the way that was available in that module?

Answer (score 0):

The only alternative I could find was 'user defined functions': https://www.arangodb.com/docs/stable/aql/extending.html.

Once you have a **UDF** defined, say `userFunc`, you could run a query like:

```
FOR v, e, p in MIN..MAX
INBOUND|OUTBOUND|ANY @startingNode
GRAPH @graph //or edge list
[PRUNE]
[OPTIONS]
LET vProcessed = userFunc(v)
//... further clauses operate on vProcessed
```

A user function defined this way could potentially visit **both** nodes and edges, which I'm not sure if the client driver could.

**Note:** The 'visitor' can only run **after** the `PRUNE` clause, due to AQL's permitted syntax schema.